# Getting HTML instead of JSON in response.data [NodeJS, Axios, VueJS]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, axios

I am fairly new to both NodeJS and VueJS, I want to send an object called user, from a `GET route` in a NodeJS backend app, and get it in my vueJS component using axios to handle the request. All what I am getting is an html string in the response.data instead of the user's JSON.
How can I get a JSON object?

I tried adding `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');` in the GET router before doing res.json(user) to send the user, but same html data in vue.

I have had another error and I used CORS, I included `app.use(cors())` in my nodeJS app.js file, do I need to add some configuration to it to get the JSON object?

this is from routes/index.js (where I have the '/dashboard' GET router)

```
router.get('/dashboard', function(req, res, next) {

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  //some code (to get user...)
  // the below line displays the user data as JSON in the browser
  res.json(user);
}
```

this is from the vue component where I want to get the user as a JSON object and use it:

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    export default {
        name: 'DashboardIndex',
        data(){
            return {
                user: {},
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getUser(){
                axios
                .get("http://localhost:3000/dashboard/")
                .then(response => {
                    // response.data returns an html string
                    console.log(response);
                    this.user = response.data;
                })
                .catch(error => alert(error));
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getUser();
        }
    }
</script>
```

this is the response that I log to the console:

```
{data: "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" id="payments-over…14], Mon, 07 Oct 2019 09:23:47 GMT...</html>", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
```

I want the user object to be sent as a JSON object and be able to get it in the vue component.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: please show us `//some code (to get user...)`.

Comment: does anything in the response look like the JSON you want?

Comment: 1. Check what's being transferred in each direction by studying the relevant request in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools. 2. Try hitting the URL `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/` directly from your browser address bar, cut out the UI entirely, see whether the server responds as expected. Again be sure to use the Network tab to see the raw response. 3. Put some logging in your server route to confirm that it's being hit and that the value of `user` is what it should be. It may be that an earlier route is responding.

Comment: Yes I do get the JSON string in the response, I can see it in the browser!